# System policy prevents wifi scans (and root pass for power)

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, arch-arm

The subject is an arch arm raspberry pi 3 (lxqt)
I am prompted every time when I open network manager or want to reboot for a root password.

I have the following modifications in my `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias      REBOOT = /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff,
/usr/bin/shutdown -h now Cmnd_Alias      NETWORK = /usr/bin/netctl,
/usr/bin/nm-applet, /usr/bin/nm-connection-editor, /usr/bin/nm-online,
/usr/bin/nmcli, /usr/bin/nmtui, /usr/bin/nmtui-connect,
/usr/bin/nmtui-edit, /usr/bin/nmtui-hostname

%network ALL=(ROOT) NOPASSWD: NETWORK 

%power ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: POWER
```

tried (ALL) and (ROOT) for both, neither did work.

My `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy` file contains properly:

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
```

and added

```
<allow_any>yes</allow_any>
```

Still it did not fix my problem. Weirly enough even if I dont provide the root password the wifi scan for instance will go through and I see the available connections.

I read most posts (10 years old or so) but they did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late for the answer. I have the same problem just now for setting up WiFi with Fedora 33 on Raspberry Pi 4. I use the `no` instead of `yes` on the following to fix the issue:

```
<allow_any>no</allow_any>
```

Hope this help.